# ClassFormatError occured : Unknown constant tag 32 in class file Template_1007$_run_closure1_closure2

Tags: java, playframework-1.x

I have a java  controller class , name DataManageMent.java . I have found this error :

> ClassFormatError occured : Unknown constant tag 32 in class file
>   Template_1007$_run_closure1_closure2

[image: Here is my screenshot]

Here is my code :

```
public static void viewDetails(Long id){

        String users = session.get("username");

        User user = User.findByName(users);

        List<Water> waterList=new ArrayList<Water>();
        List<Sanitation> sanitationList =new ArrayList<Sanitation>();
        List<SportsRecreation> sportsRecreationList =new ArrayList<SportsRecreation>();
        List<SchoolEnvironment> schoolEnvironmentList =new ArrayList<SchoolEnvironment>();

        List<GeoDivision> geoDivisionList = GeoDivision.findAll();
        List<GeoDistrict> geoDistrictList = GeoDistrict.findAll();
        List<GeoUpazilla> geoUpazillaList = GeoUpazilla.findAll();
        List<Form> formList = Form.findAll();
        List<SchoolInformation> schoolList = SchoolInformation.findAll();

        Long roleId = user.role.id;

        if(roleId==3){

            Long schoolId = user.school.id;
            Logger.info("school: " + schoolId + "roleId: " + roleId);

            waterList=Water.find("school_id=?",schoolId).fetch();
            Logger.info("size: " + waterList.size());
            sanitationList = Sanitation.find("school_id=?",schoolId).fetch();
            sportsRecreationList = SportsRecreation.find("school_id=?",schoolId).fetch();
            schoolEnvironmentList = SchoolEnvironment.find("school_id=?",schoolId).fetch();

            render(geoDivisionList, geoDistrictList, geoUpazillaList,schoolList, formList,waterList,sanitationList,sportsRecreationList,schoolEnvironmentList);
        }

        else if(roleId!=3){

            waterList = Water.findAll();
            Logger.info("size: " + waterList.size());
            sanitationList = Sanitation.findAll();
            sportsRecreationList = SportsRecreation.findAll();
            schoolEnvironmentList = SchoolEnvironment.findAll();

            render(geoDivisionList, geoDistrictList, geoUpazillaList,schoolList, formList,waterList,sanitationList,sportsRecreationList,schoolEnvironmentList);
        }
    }
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The size of view page was bigger . I have to make an external js and transfer the javascript code to it.And then,finally it works.